# What should I do? what is wrong ? error ("missing VALUES keyword")

Tags: sql

```
INSERT INTO T_RECEITA_MEDICAMENTO (cd_receita, cd_medicamento, posologia)
INSERT INTO T_RECEITA_MEDICAMENTO VALUES (1, 2, '2x ao dia');
INSERT INTO T_RECEITA_MEDICAMENTO VALUES (2, 1, '6x ao dia');
INSERT INTO T_RECEITA_MEDICAMENTO VALUES (3, 3, '1 comprimido a cada 12 horas');
INSERT INTO T_RECEITA_MEDICAMENTO VALUES (2, 1, 'Cloridrato de Metformina');
```

ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword. What is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `Values` keyword in first `Insert` statement:

```
INSERT INTO T_RECEITA_MEDICAMENTO (cd_receita, cd_medicamento, posologia)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove each insert into, excluding the first line

Syntax:

```
Insert into my_table_name (column1,column2)
Values ('var1', 'var2);
```